# PayPal:Python Incoming JSON request does not map to API request

Tags: python, json, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Am trying to integrate paypal sdk in my website using the paypal-python-SDK. When I type the item_list manually like this:

```
{"name": "Sparzy", "sku": "music beat", "price": "25.0", "currency": "USD", "quantity": 1}
```

But when I try to add it in form of a variable e.g.

```
itemlist = {"name": "Sparzy", "sku": "music beat", "price": "25.0", "currency": "USD", "quantity": 1}
```

I get the following error:

```
Payment Error: {u'message': u'Incoming JSON request does not map to API request', u'debug_id': u'394fa35b1b301', u'name': u'MALFORMED_REQUEST', u'information_link': u'https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST'}
```

I really need it as a variable so that I can dynamically generate the list when a user add producs to cart. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where are you using `itemlist`?

Comment: "transactions": [{
                "item_list": {
                    "items": [ itemlist ] },
                "amount": {
                  "total": total,
                  "currency": "USD" },
                "description": "This is the payment transaction description." }]

Comment: You will need to call `json.dumps()` on your last object just before you send your request to paypal.

Comment: "{\"name\": \"Sparzy\", \"sku\": \"music beat\", \"price\": \"25.0\", \"currency\": \"USD\", \"quantity\": 1}" This is the value I get when I do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use dictonnary as JSON. Both syntaxes are similar but dictionnaries are Python structure while JSON is a data format.

In comments you said use your `itemlist` dictionnary like:

```
"transactions": [{
    "item_list": { "items": [ itemlist ] }, 
    "amount": { "total": total, "currency": "USD" }, 
    "description": "This is the payment transaction description." 
}]
```

If this is your entiere JSON data you want to send, you can do something like:

```
dict_data = "transactions": [{
    "item_list": { "items": [ itemlist ] }, 
    "amount": { "total": total, "currency": "USD" }, 
    "description": "This is the payment transaction description." 
}])
json_data = json.dumps(dict_data)
```

`json.dumps()` take a structure and parse it in JSON formatted **string**.
If you are doing something like:

```
json_data = "transactions": [{
    "item_list": { "items": [ json.dumps(itemlist) ] }, 
    "amount": { "total": total, "currency": "USD" }, 
    "description": "This is the payment transaction description." 
}])
```

You are wrong because element `transacations:item_list` will be a list of **strings** and not a list of **dicts**.
It's important to understand that JSON is just a way to format a structure, you could parse you dict in XML in the exact same way by example.

So be sure to compute data you want to send in a dictionnary first, then, at the really end, parse the whole data in JSON string.

Comment: Am using flask framework. It usually doesn't accept "print" let me try the JSON solution.

Comment: "{\"name\": \"Sparzy\", \"sku\": \"music beat\", \"price\": \"25.0\", \"currency\": \"USD\", \"quantity\": 1}" this is what I get

Comment: This is a well formated JSON string, it _should_ be ok. Please update your post to give more infos and code. How do you call it manually and with form.

Comment: Not sure I'm right, but I tried something else according to one of your comments